# Find & replace values

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**Working Code:**

> Find Word "STIG" , remove it and save to .txt file
> , I'm able to do it using following code:

```
$content | Where-Object { -not $_.Contains('STIG') } | set-content $file
```

**Problem**:

I'm not able to find word "(non-R2)" and Replace it with "non-R2" and Save values to text file.

```
SAMPLE:
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2008_R2_Benchmark_v3.2.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2012_(non-R2)_Benchmark_v2.2.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2012_R2_Benchmark_v2.4.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2016_RTM_(Release_1607)_Benchmark_v1.2.0-xccdf
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2016_STIG_Benchmark_v1.0.0-xccdf.xml
```

```
**Desired Result**
 Will not contain line having "STIG" & will have replaced value "non-R2" (without brackets) and Save to Txt file:

CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2008_R2_Benchmark_v3.2.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2012_non-R2_Benchmark_v2.2.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2012_R2_Benchmark_v2.4.0-xccdf.xml
CIS_Microsoft_Windows_Server_2016_RTM_(Release_1607)_Benchmark_v1.2.0-xccdf
```

Comment: `$content.Replace("(non-R2)","non-R2")`

Comment: I recommend the `.Replace()` method that Luuk, posted above me. It reads characters as literals so there's (*usually*) no need to escape them, such as, using `-Replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((Get-Content -Path "sample.txt"  ) -replace '\(non-R2\)','non-R2' ) | Set-Content "sample2.txt"
```

This will read the content of `sample.txt`, then replace "(non-R2)" to "non-R2", and then write the results to `sample2.txt`.